# Avoid serialize to null using Circe json serializer

Tags: json, scala, circe

How to avoid serializing None to null using Circe json serializer? I am not able to force this library to skip serializing fields which are None. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. We can provide implicit variable of instance Printer with our configuration. 
https://github.com/circe/circe/blob/master/modules/core/shared/src/main/scala/io/circe/Printer.scala
We can set dropNullKeys to null and everything is working like a charm.

Comment: `dropNullKeys` has now been changed to `dropNullValues` - see also here: [link](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/585)