# How do I create an exclusion Encoder in Circe?

Tags: json, scala, circe

In my application, I need to have some `Option`s encode to `null` when empty and others excluded when empty. Based on the signature of `Encoder` this doesn't seem to be possible for a special type wrapping `Option`.  Is there a good way to handle this?

**Edit**: In other answers (like [Encoding Scala None to JSON value using circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358455/encoding-scala-none-to-json-value-using-circe)) this question has been touched upon but with no suitable solution. In all of the answers supplied it is an explicit workaround that must be dealt with. I'm looking for a more general fix going forward. This is ultimately something that seems to be a missing feature in Circe, and (according to @travis-brown) will be addressed in the near future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding Scala None to JSON value using circe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358455/encoding-scala-none-to-json-value-using-circe)